# my code is not connecting to MONGODB showing promise pending error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();

const connect = mongoose
  .connect(
    'mongodb+srv://<username<password>@cluster0.nrtxpty.mongodb.net/node-angular?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
  )
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connected To DataBase');
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('connection failed', connect);
  });

const Registration = require('./models/registration');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept'
  );
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
    'GET,POST,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS'
  );
  next();
});

app.post('/api/register', (req, res, next) => {
  const register = new Registration({
    name: req.body.name,
    password: req.body.password,
  });
  console.log(register);
  register.save();
  res.status(201).json({
    message: 'Registered Succesfully!!!',
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

my code didn't connect to the MongoDB cluster on my work PC but it is connecting to my Personal PC. What is the error?
The error showing is connection failed Promise {  }.What will be the error? Any Help appreciated.

Comment: it is single line in code

Comment: you are using atlas?  did you enable your work pc IP in atlas?

Comment: yes I enabled my work pc in atlas

Comment: The `catch` probably receives an `error` argument. You should try inspecting that. It may contain valuable information